# How do I go from an <input> of type checkbox to a MySQL row of type bool?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I have

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hide"/>
```

Based on whether it is checked, what should be the corresponding value of

```
$_POST['hide']
```

supposed to be????

For me it's `null` whether or not the `input` was checked. I'm parsing the parent `form` and submitting it with

```
    formdata = new FormData($('#proj-form')[0]); 
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
```

Is there something I have to do before submitting the form? I hate having to short-stop form submissions to manually set `value`s .... I like to do things elegantly if possible.

Comment: @DeDee That was a type-o. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your direct question about what the value should be, if unchecked the field won't be posted at all, and if checked the posted value will be from the `value` attribute on the input.

For example, given:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hide" value="1"/>
```

Unchecked, `array_key_exists('hide',$_POST) === FALSE` - depending on your PHP config this might evaluate to `null`, or throw a warning. Checked you'll get `1`.

Comment: Is there a way without Javascript to make the input's value linked to whether it is checked?

Comment: You could solve this in PHP such as `if(!array_key_exists('hide',$_POST)){ $_POST['hide'] = 0;}`